# Synology Diskstation - Setting up Shares

Tags: nas, synology

I am trying to allow users on my Synology Diskstation to share folders with eachother from their homes.

So, let's say this is my folder structure:

```
homes
 - william
   - pictures
     - tahoe
 - kristie
```

If I give kristie read permissions for the 'tahoe' folder, I would expect that the folder would show up on her Filestation.  It doesn't.

Then I thought that maybe she could follow the "access link" that is shown in the properties of the folder.  However, when she tried to follow that link it says that the folder does not exist.

I then tried to create a shared link with her.  This shared link works when she tries to access the files from the local network, however, it seems to redirect the request to the local IP of the diskdrive - which means that it does not work from external networks.

I feel like I am missing something - this shouldn't be so hard!

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting, as this all seems entirely reasonable. You can either share `tahoe` as its own share, and grant her permissions to it, or move the content out of the home into an existing share. If a user lacks access to a share, they cannot navigate to a subdirectory within that share. As for the link target, Synology cannot know anything about your network configuration such that it could construct links that work externally (there might be many external addresses that access the device) so the user would have to edit the link to use a valid external address.

Comment: In "External Access > Advanced" you can specify the Hostname for the Synology - so it definitely should be aware of how it can be accessed externally.  Additionally, I would disagree with your other point as well - if you create a shared link for a folder in Dropbox, the permissions of the parent folder are irrelevant - the link simply gives someone access to only the specific folder and everything within it.

Comment: FYI  I fixed most of my issues by disabling the QuickConnect feature and only generating links on a subdomain pointing to my network.